# Creating a single camel application bundle with all dependencies using maven3

Tags: apache-camel, maven-3, apache-karaf, karaf, apache-servicemix

I am trying to create a camel application bundle so that I can run it in service mix 6.1.0 under karaf.

As per Ralf I tried the KAR format. My `pom.xml` looks like below:-

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.jabong.orchestratorservice</groupId>
    <artifactId>basecomponent</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>kar</packaging>
    <name>basecomponent</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.13</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.arnabk</groupId>
            <artifactId>java-dogstatsd-client</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20151123</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-jetty</artifactId>
            <version>2.16.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-http4</artifactId>
            <version>2.16.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.16.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.13</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-test</artifactId>
            <version>2.16.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>
                com.googlecode.maven-java-formatter-plugin
            </groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-java-formatter-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.logstash.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logstash-logback-encoder</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.13</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.13</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>easyb</id>
            <!-- When maven.test.skip is defined, don't run easyb tests. Ideally, 
                it should check for skipTests flag too,but maven profile activation doesn't 
                support multiple variables. More details is here http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MNG-3328. 
                There is also easyb ticket created for this issue: https://code.google.com/p/easyb/issues/detail?id=192. -->
            <activation>
                <property>
                    <name>!maven.test.skip</name>
                </property>
            </activation>

            <build>
                <pluginManagement>
                    <plugins>
                        <plugin>
                            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                            <version>3.3</version>
                            <configuration>
                                <source>1.8</source>
                                <target>1.8</target>
                            </configuration>
                        </plugin>
                    </plugins>
                </pluginManagement>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.easyb</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-easyb-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>0.9</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>test</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                        <configuration>
                            <storyType>html</storyType>
                            <storyReport>${project.build.directory}/easyb/stories.txt</storyReport>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>com.googlecode.maven-java-formatter-plugin</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-java-formatter-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>0.4</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <compilerSource>1.8</compilerSource>
                            <compilerCompliance>1.8</compilerCompliance>
                            <compilerTargetPlatform>1.8</compilerTargetPlatform>
                            <configFile>${project.basedir}/code_format_java.xml</configFile>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
                        <extensions>true</extensions>
                        <configuration>
                            <instructions>
                                <Bundle-SymbolicName>${project.artifactId}</Bundle-SymbolicName>
                                <Bundle-Description>${project.description}</Bundle-Description>
                                <Import-Package>*;resolution:=optional</Import-Package>                             
                            </instructions>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.karaf.tooling</groupId>
                        <artifactId>karaf-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>4.0.0</version>
                        <extensions>true</extensions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>

        </profile>
    </profiles>

</project>
```

On doing `mvn install` I am getting the below error:-

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for com.jabong.orchestratorservice:basecomponent:kar:1.0
[WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.apache.felix:maven-bundle-plugin is missing. @ line 152, column 14
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.
[WARNING] 
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building basecomponent 1.0
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.7:resources (default-resources) @ basecomponent ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 4 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- karaf-maven-plugin:4.0.0:features-generate-descriptor (default-features-generate-descriptor) @ basecomponent ---
[INFO] Generating feature descriptor file /home/jabong/code/github.com/jabong/orchestrator-service/basecomponent/target/feature/feature.xml
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/1.5.5/plexus-utils-1.5.5.jar
Exception in thread "pool-1-thread-1" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.AbstractHttpClientWagon.getReadTimeout()I
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.AbstractHttpClientWagon.execute(AbstractHttpClientWagon.java:798)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.AbstractHttpClientWagon.fillInputData(AbstractHttpClientWagon.java:1000)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.AbstractHttpClientWagon.fillInputData(AbstractHttpClientWagon.java:977)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.StreamWagon.getInputStream(StreamWagon.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.StreamWagon.getIfNewer(StreamWagon.java:88)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.StreamWagon.get(StreamWagon.java:61)
    at org.sonatype.aether.connector.wagon.WagonRepositoryConnector$GetTask.run(WagonRepositoryConnector.java:601)
    at org.sonatype.aether.util.concurrency.RunnableErrorForwarder$1.run(RunnableErrorForwarder.java:60)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2.574s
[INFO] Finished at: Wed Feb 24 23:12:56 IST 2016
[INFO] Final Memory: 21M/341M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.karaf.tooling:karaf-maven-plugin:4.0.0:features-generate-descriptor (default-features-generate-descriptor) on project basecomponent: Execution default-features-generate-descriptor of goal org.apache.karaf.tooling:karaf-maven-plugin:4.0.0:features-generate-descriptor failed: An API incompatibility was encountered while executing org.apache.karaf.tooling:karaf-maven-plugin:4.0.0:features-generate-descriptor: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.AbstractHttpClientWagon.getReadTimeout()I
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] realm =    plugin>org.apache.karaf.tooling:karaf-maven-plugin:4.0.0
[ERROR] strategy = org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy
[ERROR] urls[0] = file:/home/jabong/.m2/repository/org/apache/karaf/tooling/karaf-maven-plugin/4.0.0/karaf-maven-plugin-4.0.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[1] = file:/home/jabong/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/sisu/sisu-inject-bean/2.1.1/sisu-inject-bean-2.1.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[2] = file:/home/jabong/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/sisu/sisu-guice/2.9.4/sisu-guice-2.9.4-no_aop.jar
[ERROR] urls[3] = file:/home/jabong/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/aether/aether-util/1.11/aether-util-1.11.jar
[ERROR] urls[4] = file:/home/jabong/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/aether/aether-api/0.9.0.M2/aether-api-0.9.0.M2.jar
[ERROR] urls[5] = file:/home/jabong/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/aether/aether-util/0.9.0.M2/aether-util-0.9.0.M2.jar
[ERROR] urls[6] = file:/home/jabong/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-interpolation/1.14/plexus-interpolation-1.14.jar
[ERROR] urls[7] = file:/home/jabong/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-component-annotations/1.5.5/plexus-component-annotations-1.5.5.jar
[ERROR] urls[8] = file:/home/jabong/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/plexus/plexus-sec-dispatcher/1.3/plexus-sec-dispatcher-1.3.jar
[ERROR] urls[9] = file:/home/jabong/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/plexus/plexus-cipher/1.4/plexus-cipher-1.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[10] = file:/home/jabong/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/plugin-tools/maven-plugin-annotations/3.3/maven-plugin-annotations-3.3.jar
[ERROR] urls[11] = file:/home/jabong/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/wagon/wagon-http/2.8/wagon-http-2.8.jar
[ERROR] urls[12] = file:/home/jabong/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/wagon/wagon-http-shared/2.8/wagon-http-shared-2.8.jar
[ERROR] urls[13] = file:/home/jabong/.m2/repository/org/jsoup/jsoup/1.7.2/jsoup-1.7.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[14] = file:/home/jabong/.m2/repository/commons-lang/commons-lang/2.6/commons-lang-2.6.jar
[ERROR] urls[15] = file:/home/jabong/.m2/repository/commons-io/commons-io/2.2/commons-io-2.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[16] = file:/home/jabong/.m2/repository/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpclient/4.3.5/httpclient-4.3.5.jar
[ERROR] urls[17] = file:/home/jabong/.m2/repository/commons-codec/commons-codec/1.6/commons-codec-1.6.jar
[ERROR] urls[18] = file:/home/jabong/.m2/repository/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.1.3/commons-logging-1.1.3.jar
[ERROR] urls[19] = file:/home/jabong/.m2/repository/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpcore/4.3.2/httpcore-4.3.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[20] = file:/home/jabong/.m2/repository/org/apache/karaf/org.apache.karaf.util/4.0.0/org.apache.karaf.util-4.0.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[21] = file:/home/jabong/.m2/repository/org/apache/felix/org.apache.felix.utils/1.8.0/org.apache.felix.utils-1.8.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[22] = file:/home/jabong/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.12/slf4j-api-1.7.12.jar
[ERROR] urls[23] = file:/home/jabong/.m2/repository/org/apache/karaf/jaas/org.apache.karaf.jaas.boot/4.0.0/org.apache.karaf.jaas.boot-4.0.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[24] = file:/home/jabong/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-jdk14/1.7.12/slf4j-jdk14-1.7.12.jar
[ERROR] urls[25] = file:/home/jabong/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/shared/maven-filtering/1.0-beta-4/maven-filtering-1.0-beta-4.jar
[ERROR] urls[26] = file:/home/jabong/.m2/repository/junit/junit/3.8.1/junit-3.8.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[27] = file:/home/jabong/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/plexus/plexus-build-api/0.0.4/plexus-build-api-0.0.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[28] = file:/home/jabong/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/3.0/plexus-utils-3.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[29] = file:/home/jabong/.m2/repository/org/apache/felix/maven-bundle-plugin/2.5.4/maven-bundle-plugin-2.5.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[30] = file:/home/jabong/.m2/repository/biz/aQute/bnd/biz.aQute.bndlib/2.4.1/biz.aQute.bndlib-2.4.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[31] = file:/home/jabong/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/maven-archiver/2.5/maven-archiver-2.5.jar
[ERROR] urls[32] = file:/home/jabong/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-archiver/2.1/plexus-archiver-2.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[33] = file:/home/jabong/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-io/2.0.2/plexus-io-2.0.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[34] = file:/home/jabong/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/shared/maven-dependency-tree/2.1/maven-dependency-tree-2.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[35] = file:/home/jabong/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/doxia/doxia-sink-api/1.0/doxia-sink-api-1.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[36] = file:/home/jabong/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/doxia/doxia-site-renderer/1.0/doxia-site-renderer-1.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[37] = file:/home/jabong/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/doxia/doxia-core/1.0/doxia-core-1.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[38] = file:/home/jabong/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-i18n/1.0-beta-7/plexus-i18n-1.0-beta-7.jar
[ERROR] urls[39] = file:/home/jabong/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-velocity/1.1.7/plexus-velocity-1.1.7.jar
[ERROR] urls[40] = file:/home/jabong/.m2/repository/org/apache/velocity/velocity/1.5/velocity-1.5.jar
[ERROR] urls[41] = file:/home/jabong/.m2/repository/oro/oro/2.0.8/oro-2.0.8.jar
[ERROR] urls[42] = file:/home/jabong/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/doxia/doxia-decoration-model/1.0/doxia-decoration-model-1.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[43] = file:/home/jabong/.m2/repository/commons-collections/commons-collections/3.2/commons-collections-3.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[44] = file:/home/jabong/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/doxia/doxia-module-apt/1.0/doxia-module-apt-1.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[45] = file:/home/jabong/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/doxia/doxia-module-fml/1.0/doxia-module-fml-1.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[46] = file:/home/jabong/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/doxia/doxia-module-xdoc/1.0/doxia-module-xdoc-1.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[47] = file:/home/jabong/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/doxia/doxia-module-xhtml/1.0/doxia-module-xhtml-1.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[48] = file:/home/jabong/.m2/repository/org/apache/felix/org.apache.felix.fileinstall/3.5.0/org.apache.felix.fileinstall-3.5.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[49] = file:/home/jabong/.m2/repository/org/apache/karaf/features/org.apache.karaf.features.core/4.0.0/org.apache.karaf.features.core-4.0.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[50] = file:/home/jabong/.m2/repository/org/apache/karaf/profile/org.apache.karaf.profile.core/4.0.0/org.apache.karaf.profile.core-4.0.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[51] = file:/home/jabong/.m2/repository/org/apache/felix/org.apache.felix.resolver/1.4.0/org.apache.felix.resolver-1.4.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[52] = file:/home/jabong/.m2/repository/org/ops4j/pax/url/pax-url-wrap/2.4.1/pax-url-wrap-2.4.1-uber.jar
[ERROR] urls[53] = file:/home/jabong/.m2/repository/org/ops4j/base/ops4j-base-net/1.4.0/ops4j-base-net-1.4.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[54] = file:/home/jabong/.m2/repository/org/ops4j/base/ops4j-base-lang/1.5.0/ops4j-base-lang-1.5.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[55] = file:/home/jabong/.m2/repository/org/ops4j/base/ops4j-base-monitors/1.4.0/ops4j-base-monitors-1.4.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[56] = file:/home/jabong/.m2/repository/org/ops4j/pax/swissbox/pax-swissbox-bnd/1.8.1/pax-swissbox-bnd-1.8.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[57] = file:/home/jabong/.m2/repository/biz/aQute/bnd/bndlib/2.4.0/bndlib-2.4.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[58] = file:/home/jabong/.m2/repository/org/ops4j/pax/url/pax-url-commons/2.4.1/pax-url-commons-2.4.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[59] = file:/home/jabong/.m2/repository/org/ops4j/pax/swissbox/pax-swissbox-property/1.8.1/pax-swissbox-property-1.8.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[60] = file:/home/jabong/.m2/repository/org/ops4j/base/ops4j-base-util-property/1.5.0/ops4j-base-util-property-1.5.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[61] = file:/home/jabong/.m2/repository/org/ops4j/pax/url/pax-url-aether/2.4.1/pax-url-aether-2.4.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[62] = file:/home/jabong/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/jcl-over-slf4j/1.7.12/jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.12.jar
[ERROR] urls[63] = file:/home/jabong/.m2/repository/org/ops4j/pax/url/pax-url-war/2.4.1/pax-url-war-2.4.1-uber.jar
[ERROR] urls[64] = file:/home/jabong/.m2/repository/org/ops4j/pax/swissbox/pax-swissbox-optional-jcl/1.8.1/pax-swissbox-optional-jcl-1.8.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[65] = file:/home/jabong/.m2/repository/org/apache/karaf/deployer/org.apache.karaf.deployer.spring/4.0.0/org.apache.karaf.deployer.spring-4.0.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[66] = file:/home/jabong/.m2/repository/org/apache/karaf/deployer/org.apache.karaf.deployer.blueprint/4.0.0/org.apache.karaf.deployer.blueprint-4.0.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[67] = file:/home/jabong/.m2/repository/org/apache/karaf/deployer/org.apache.karaf.deployer.features/4.0.0/org.apache.karaf.deployer.features-4.0.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[68] = file:/home/jabong/.m2/repository/org/apache/karaf/deployer/org.apache.karaf.deployer.kar/4.0.0/org.apache.karaf.deployer.kar-4.0.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[69] = file:/home/jabong/.m2/repository/org/apache/karaf/kar/org.apache.karaf.kar.core/4.0.0/org.apache.karaf.kar.core-4.0.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[70] = file:/home/jabong/.m2/repository/org/apache/karaf/shell/org.apache.karaf.shell.console/4.0.0/org.apache.karaf.shell.console-4.0.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[71] = file:/home/jabong/.m2/repository/jline/jline/2.12.1/jline-2.12.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[72] = file:/home/jabong/.m2/repository/org/apache/karaf/jaas/org.apache.karaf.jaas.modules/4.0.0/org.apache.karaf.jaas.modules-4.0.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[73] = file:/home/jabong/.m2/repository/org/apache/karaf/jaas/org.apache.karaf.jaas.config/4.0.0/org.apache.karaf.jaas.config-4.0.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[74] = file:/home/jabong/.m2/repository/org/apache/karaf/shell/org.apache.karaf.shell.core/4.0.0/org.apache.karaf.shell.core-4.0.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[75] = file:/home/jabong/.m2/repository/org/apache/sshd/sshd-core/0.14.0/sshd-core-0.14.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[76] = file:/home/jabong/.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/commons-compress/1.9/commons-compress-1.9.jar
[ERROR] urls[77] = file:/home/jabong/.m2/repository/org/osgi/org.osgi.core/6.0.0/org.osgi.core-6.0.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[78] = file:/home/jabong/.m2/repository/org/apache/xbean/xbean-finder-shaded/3.18/xbean-finder-shaded-3.18.jar
[ERROR] urls[79] = file:/home/jabong/.m2/repository/org/apache/xbean/xbean-asm5-shaded/3.18/xbean-asm5-shaded-3.18.jar
[ERROR] Number of foreign imports: 1
[ERROR] import: Entry[import  from realm ClassRealm[project>com.jabong.orchestratorservice:basecomponent:1.0, parent: ClassRealm[maven.api, parent: null]]]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginContainerException
jabong@jabong1143:~/code/github.com/jabong/orchestrator-service/basecomponent$
```

Karaf version is reporting 3.0.5.

```
karaf@root>info
Karaf
  Karaf version               3.0.5
  Karaf home                  /home/jabong/Downloads/software/dev/apache-servicemix-6.1.0
  Karaf base                  /home/jabong/Downloads/software/dev/apache-servicemix-6.1.0
  Karaf etc                   /home/jabong/Downloads/software/dev/apache-servicemix-6.1.0/etc
  OSGi Framework              org.apache.felix.framework - 4.2.1
```

So tried `karaf-maven-plugin` with version 3.0.5. But still getting same error.

The error seems to be an issue with maven 3.0.4 that I was using as mentioned [here](https://github.com/cemerick/pomegranate/issues/25). After upgrading maven to 3.2.5 I am not getting the issue.

Comment: I never used Servicemix, but as it is based on Karaf I assume the concept is the same: In Karaf you can describe your application and its dependencies with a feature repository file. You either use the feature descriptor in combination with a local Maven repository or you package it all up in a [KAR file](https://karaf.apache.org/manual/latest/users-guide/kar.html) that you can place in Karaf's deploy folder.

Comment: Yeah @Ralf KAR meets my requirement. But I am getting some error. I have updated my question.

Comment: @Ralf - Can you write your comment as answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cannot tell what causes your exact problem, but there are several issues with your POM file:

1. You should not define a packaging type that is implemented in a bundle you only pull in if a certain profile is active.
2. The packaging type has to be `bundle`, not `kar`. Instead you trigger the creation of the feature descriptor and KAR artifact via the karaf plugin configuration.
3. The Karaf plugin version should match your Karaf version.
4. You should define the Camel version (better all versions of your dependencies) as a property in your POM so it can be re-used in several places.
5. Karaf ships with Camel. Instead of loading Camel bundles one by one through your generated feature file, driven by the POM, you can set the scope of all your Camel dependencies to `provided` and instead declare a feature dependency in a template feature.xml. This is more the KAR/feature way of doing things, but less the Maven way as your POM does not drive all your dependencies anymore. Your choice.

I suggest a POM along these lines:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
   <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
   <artifactId>your-artifact</artifactId>
   <packaging>bundle</packaging>

   <properties>
      <camel.version>2.16.1</camel.version>
      <!-- ... -->
   </properties>

   <build>
      <plugins>
         <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
         </plugin>

         <!-- Documentation at http://felix.apache.org/site/apache-felix-maven-bundle-plugin-bnd.html -->
         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
         </plugin>

         <!-- Documentation at https://karaf.apache.org/manual/latest/developers-guide/karaf-maven-plugin.html -->
         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.karaf.tooling</groupId>
            <artifactId>karaf-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
               <aggregateFeatures>false</aggregateFeatures>
               <includeTransitiveDependency>true</includeTransitiveDependency>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
               <execution>
                  <id>generate-karaf-artifacts</id>
                  <goals>
                     <goal>features-generate-descriptor</goal>
                     <goal>kar</goal>
                  </goals>
               </execution>
            </executions>
         </plugin>
      </plugins>
   </build>

   <dependencies>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
         <artifactId>camel-core</artifactId>
         <version>${camel.version}</version>
         <scope>provided</scope>
      </dependency>

      <!-- ... -->
   </dependencies>
</project>
```

Create a template feature.xml in `src/main/feature` like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<features xmlns="http://karaf.apache.org/xmlns/features/v1.3.0" name="your-feature-repo-name">
    <feature name="${project.artifactId}" version="${project.version}" description="Describe your feature">
        <feature version="${camel.version}">camel-jetty</feature>
        <feature version="${camel.version}">camel-netty4-http</feature>
        <!-- This is to pull in the bundle you built. -->
        <bundle start-level="91">mvn:${project.groupId}/${project.artifactId}/${project.version}</bundle>
    </feature>
</features>
```

The template is picked up by the Karaf plugin and it adds the rest of your dependencies to this template. Check out the result after the build in target/feature/feature.xml and/or in the KAR artifact.

Comment: Now the KAR is getting created perfectly & working fine inside Karaf. But the web console stopped working. On trying to access http://localhost:8181/system/console/bundles it is giving 404 Http Error.

Comment: @tuk, Karaf comes with a [web console feature](https://karaf.apache.org/index/subprojects/webconsole.html). I never used it and the URL is different from yours. So might be Servicemix rolls its own?

Comment: I am on Karaf 3.0.5 & I am using web console as mentioned in https://karaf.apache.org/manual/latest/users-guide/webconsole.html

Comment: @tuk, and you installed the feature?

Comment: Yes I installed the feature using `feature:install webconsole` & the webconsole was working. But after I deployed the KAR in karaf webconsole stopped working.

Comment: @tuk, I suggest you raise another question with more details about the problem.